# unable to start redis-cli from yugabyte database

Tags: redis, yugabytedb

I'm trying run redis/yedis on the yugabyte database by following https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/yedis/quick-start/#linux.

I run the command `./bin/yb-ctl setup_redis` but I end up with the error:

```
Setting up YugaByte DB support for Redis API.
Waiting for cluster to be ready.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/yb-ctl", line 2104, in <module>
    control.run()
  File "./bin/yb-ctl", line 2081, in run
    self.args.func()
  File "./bin/yb-ctl", line 1967, in setup_redis_cmd_impl
    self.wait_for_cluster_or_raise()
  File "./bin/yb-ctl", line 1646, in wait_for_cluster_or_raise
    if not self.wait_for_cluster():
  File "./bin/yb-ctl", line 1591, in wait_for_cluster
    cmd_list_tservers = self.yb_admin_cmd_list("list_all_tablet_servers")
  File "./bin/yb-ctl", line 2036, in yb_admin_cmd_list
    raise ValueError("Cannot form yb-admin command without knowing master addresses")
ValueError: Cannot form yb-admin command without knowing master addresses
Viewing file /tmp/tmpbg32mn95:
^^^ Encountered errors ^^^
2021-12-22 16:08:27,463 INFO: Waiting for master and tserver processes to come up.
```

I have my master and tserver both running after running the commands:

```
./bin/yb-master --flagfile master.conf >& /home/doug/mark/disk1/yb-master.out &
./bin/yb-tserver --flagfile tserver.conf >& /home/doug/mark/yb-tserver.out&
```

The master config file:

```
--master_addresses=192.168.1.62:7100
--rpc_bind_addresses=192.168.1.62:7100
--fs_data_dirs=/home/doug/mark/disk1
```

The tserver config file:

```
--tserver_master_addrs=192.168.1.62:7100
--rpc_bind_addresses=192.168.1.62:9100
--start_pgsql_proxy
--pgsql_proxy_bind_address=192.168.1.62:5433
--cql_proxy_bind_address=192.168.1.62:9042
--fs_data_dirs=/home/doug/mark/disk1
```

and in the master log I can see:

```
I1223 00:08:03.023463 1527298 heartbeater.cc:340] P 419a60d5690945c8ad23c42f7ba758ba: Connected to a leader master server at 192.168.1.62:7100
I1223 00:08:03.023666 1527298 heartbeater.cc:388] P 419a60d5690945c8ad23c42f7ba758ba: Registering TS with master...
```

But I'm not sure why I can't start up the redis-cli based on the tutorial link above?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running the yb-tserver & yb-master manually, try running this command:

```
./bin/yb-admin [-master_addresses server1:port,server2:port,server3:port,...] setup_redis_table
```

Note that YEDIS API is not a focus, it must be viewed as a deprecated API for new application development purposes. ([docs link](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/yedis/))